# Navigation drawer activity in webview

Tags: android, webview, navigation-drawer

I have a web app were users can signup and post stories, i am trying to convert it into an android app using webview. What exactly i want is a navigation drawer activity after user have signed up. That means when user opens the app the webview starts but without the navigation drawer, navigation drawers only appear after the user have signed up or signed in.

I want to know is it even possible.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Activity (Can be any name) like :**WebViewScreen.java** where you need to put the `webView` and put it on launcher. So when your app starts first this webview screen will appears and if user is logged in then directly send to your Navigation Drawer activity if not then login Activity.

Your Menifest.xml will be like this :

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.WebViewScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**Go to next Activity by clicking on WebView Button :**

References :https://www.hrupin.com/2012/08/how-to-open-activity-by-android-webview-hyperlink-click-or-how-to-handle-hyperlink-click-in-android-webview

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class SendIntentByHyperlinkClickActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView webView1;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        webView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        String summary = "<html><head><title>Title of the document</title></head><body><h1><a href=\"hrupin://second_activity\">LINK to second activity</a></h1><h1><a href=\"http://www.google.com/\">Link to GOOGLE.COM</a></h1></body></html>";
        webView1.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
        webView1.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(this));
    }
}
```

Create MyWebViewClient class :

```
    import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    private Context context;

    public MyWebViewClient(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(url.equals("hrupin://second_activity")){
            Intent i = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
}
```

Comment: that's the question how to send the user to the next activity once the user click on the sign in or sign up button